# SET TIME ZONE perfomance bottleneck - Django/PosgtreSQL

Tags: python, django, postgresql

I have weird problem with Django, Postgres (everything behind Apache/mod_wsgi, on localhost). I'm logging slow queries and...

```
Mar 19 12:58:40 postgres[67952]: [2-1] LOG:  duration: 463.318 ms  statement: SET TIME ZONE 'Europe/Warsaw'
Mar 19 12:59:39 postgres[68226]: [2-1] LOG:  duration: 185.852 ms  statement: SET TIME ZONE 'Europe/Warsaw'
Mar 19 12:59:39 postgres[68225]: [2-1] LOG:  duration: 210.855 ms  statement: SET TIME ZONE 'Europe/Warsaw'
Mar 19 13:01:35 postgres[69228]: [2-1] LOG:  duration: 750.590 ms  statement: SET TIME ZONE 'Europe/Warsaw'
Mar 19 13:01:35 postgres[69226]: [2-1] LOG:  duration: 929.498 ms  statement: SET TIME ZONE 'Europe/Warsaw'
Mar 19 13:01:35 postgres[69229]: [2-1] LOG:  duration: 564.982 ms  statement: SET TIME ZONE 'Europe/Warsaw'
Mar 19 13:01:35 postgres[69227]: [2-1] LOG:  duration: 836.731 ms  statement: SET TIME ZONE 'Europe/Warsaw'
Mar 19 13:03:32 postgres[69819]: [2-1] LOG:  duration: 184.691 ms  statement: SET TIME ZONE 'Europe/Warsaw'
Mar 19 13:04:59 postgres[70442]: [2-1] LOG:  duration: 115.525 ms  statement: SET TIME ZONE 'Europe/Warsaw'
```

How such basic command can take so much time? Some kind of initiating connection problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not sure why connection overhead is so high, but after I add CONN_MAX_AGE (Django 1.6) and set it to None (persistent connection) problem goes away.